# user profile + webcam

Tags: sql

Подскажите как сделать так что бы показывались поля(типа countr:minsk усли не заполнено поле country то оно вообще не выводилось) только с той информации которую пользователь заполнил(sql) ?можно ли средствами php запустить webcam ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете циклом пройтись по колонкам (полям) экземпляра и делать print только если значение поля НЕпустое.
Со вторым не подскажу.